# Actionscript 2.0 input text properties

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I need to set input form properties to max 3 characters and number only. Can't find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
txtInput.maxChars = 3;
txtInput.restrict = "0-9";
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001603.html

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001621.html